# Hypergeometric die toss

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A fair die is tossed until a $2$ is obtained. If $X$ is the number of trials required to obtain the first $2$, what is the smallest value of $x$ for which $P(X \leq x) \geq \frac{1}{2}$?

**My thoughts**: The general formula for hypergeometric random variables is given by $p(k) = P(X=k) = \frac{C(n,k)C(N-n, r-k)}{C(n,r)}$. I need to find $x$ such that $P(x) + P(x-1) + \cdots + P(0) \geq \frac{1}{2}$. So, $k=x$. $N, n,$ and $r$ have been hard for me to find. Maybe $N=6^{X}$ (since there are $6^{X}$ possible outcomes given $X$ trials), and $n=6$, but I'd like some feedback because I'm not sure. Anyway, thanks in advance for your help.

**Source**: Finan's *A Probability Course for the Actuaries*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you certain that it is the hypergeometric distribution that you have to use? This problem looks like it can be dealt with using the negative binomial distribution.

EDIT: Okay here is how I would do it using the negative binomial distribution. Since we are interested in 1 sucess, i.e. only the first two, the negative binomial reduces to the geometric distribution that has PMF: $$ p_X(x) = p \left( 1-p \right)^{x-1} $$  X is the number of trials needed to get the first success so $x-1$ is the number of failures prior to success. The Cumulative distribution function is given by $$ CDF(x)= 1-\left( 1-p \right)^x $$

Since you are looking for the median you need to find $ x $ such that the cumulative distribution above equals $ 0.5\ \text{and}\ 1-p=5/6 $ Solve using logarithms.

Comment: It's in the hypergeomtric chapter of the book. But I'd be interested in seeing other solutions. How could the negative binomial distribution work?

Comment: More specifically this is modeled by the Geometric distribution (I know, special case of the Negative Binomial) which just counts the number of trials until the **first** success. In your case a success is rolling a $2$.

Comment: @Ioannis, $.5 = 1 - (5/6)^x$ gives $x=3.8$. But shouldn't $x$ be an integer?

Comment: This is an approximation so you round it up to the nearest integer, i.e. 4. Perhaps there is a way to do it with the Hypergeometric as well but all I have used that distrubution for is acceptance sampling.

Comment: The Hypergeometric distribution counts the number of successes when sampling **without** replacement.  Perhaps this question is in this chapter to highlight the differences between the Geometric and Hypergeometric distributions.

Comment: @Ioannis & Patrick, thanks a lot. I get it now.